# Приложение с приветствиями для фитнесс браслетов, смарт часов

Tags: android

хочу написать приложение для фитнес-браслета, как организовать его и на телефон и на устройство так, чтобы при нажатии "отправить приветствие" было две короткие вибрации, а при нажатии например "отправить взаимное приветствие" было три клика, хотел бы сделать интерфейс для обоих устройств и это все связать с сервером, который будет отправлять эти данные на другое устройство.

Comment: как это сделать можно? какие языки использовать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Начни с изучения Java